# How to detect if there is a runtime error from after executing an external .exe file from a java program?

Tags: java, windows, processbuilder

I am designing an online compiler using java. But I am stuck at defining the conditions for runtime error of the existing compiler. What should be the cases I need to handle for giving a verdict of runtime error?

I am using ProcessBuilder and Process classes to execute the external .exe file.

Answer (score 0):

The Process class gives you an exit value [`Process.exitValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue%28%29) this will typically be 0 for success and non-zero for failure/error. Depending on the compiler you are using that may be sufficient, or you may need to parse the output using something like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   builder.append(line);
   builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
String result = builder.toString();
```

Then look through `result` to find your verdict.

You may also want to look at `process.getErrorStream()` instead of `getInputStream()`.

Comment: Already done that. But if I want to execute the process "bazinga.exe" which causes a runtime error then a popup window appears. Saying "bazinga.exe has stopped working". And if I manually close that popup,then it works and returns exitvalue 0xc000 0094 as it was supposed to. How do I stop the windows popping?

the same code pattern is useful for linux where there's no popup. How do I modify this as I am using windows 7. 

[I have already disabled check for solutions to problem reports]